# Installed CWM on note 2, but the phone is not rooted

Tags: rooting, 4.3-jelly-bean, clockworkmod-recovery, superuser, heimdall

I've used Heimdall 1.4.0 on my mac to install CWM 6.0.4.3 (file name: `recovery-clockwork-6.0.4.3-n7100`) on my Samsung Note 2 GT-N7100 with android 4.3, the installation went smooth with no issues.

I then booted in recovery mode (volume up, home, power) and installed the zip file containing superuser downloaded from the link on the google play.

I then booted my phone normally, and tried if it was rooted with root checker, installed via google play. It says it's not rooted.

the application superuser starts and gives no errors,

I've done the procedure several times, also installing supersu, and installing other versions of CWM but I always got the same result.

What could I possibly have done wrong? and how can I finally get to root my phone?

thanks,

Comment: when you starting the `SuperSu` Apk app, Option (Root this phone) working?

Comment: First make sure the phone really is **not** rooted - the root checker might be wrong. Use a terminal app, execute `su` command and see what happens. If you're asked for root permission and the command executes, execute `id` command. It should say something like `uid=0` or similar - the zero is important.

Comment: there is no `sudo` in Android, that's why I posted the *exact* commands you should try

Comment: you're right, I got confused.. I never use su :P. 

my id is: 10175 and it remains unchanged if I run `id` after `su`, but I get requested no permissions or anything

Comment: Well, in that case your phone really isn't rooted. Or at least not fully. do a `ls -l /system/xbin/su` to see if at least the su binary is installed properly. If not, the problem is with the CWM-installed supersu zip or with CWM itself and would need different approach.

Comment: the su file is there... and owned by root:root, if I run `system/xbin/su` I get the same result, id doesn't change, the prompt does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rooted. AFAIK Samsung bootloaders are already unlocked, you only need to flash the recovery to get the "root"

Now for the problem.

Go to `settings->about phone` and tap the `build number` 7 times to enable `developer options`. Then go to `settings->developer options` and there you should be an option similar to `root access`. Make sure you select `Apps` or `Apps and ADB` (recommended) in it and you should have root access.

If there is no such option, download and flash [SuperSU](https://download.chainfire.eu/396/supersu/) via recovery and you should have root access later.

And that addition of "255|" in indicates you being in root user mode and accessing terminal as root. So its a positive sign here as well.

Alternatively, in case you failed to get the root to work, you can also flash 
some custom ROM like [Cyanogenmod](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=n7100) via recovery.

But rest assured, you are rooted. Its probably some bug and flashing supersu should probably fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have any root option in the developer options, Which Supersu should I install? the instructions I followed include the 0.96, which didn't work, then I tried installing the 2.46 but it didn't work either

Comment: try the latest, 2.94. Another thing, in terminal emulator run the command-> "ls /system/xbin" without quotes and tell me output if you can?

Comment: it has two files: su and dexdump owned by root

Comment: ok, the su file is the superuser binary or the root permissions in rough words. So supersu is properly installed. Check the supersu settings? It has an option to block root calls, make sure its disabled and default "Root access" is set to "Prompt"

Comment: I have removed supersu, and installed superuser instead (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.superuser&hl=en), that's the su that I have

Comment: I've used cwm to install 2.96 beta, after booting it asked me to update supersu, and it prompted me to do it via CWM, it rebooted automatically in CWM and asked me if I wanted to "fix root" I said yes, and it booted again, root checker still says I'm unrooted (though it takes a lot of time to say it now) and I get again the supersu update request.

Comment: First, dont select that "fix root" option in CMD again, that wont help. Second, it would have asked you to "Update *Binaries". So were you able to install them? You will have to install binaries to gain root, else root wont work....

Comment: yeee I got it to re update again, and it did all the same, but now my phone seems to be rooted, according to root checker and according to the other app: device control. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Glad it worked, your welcome :)

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh "Besides you can only install custom recovery if you are rooted." Sure about that? AFAIK the only condition here is the device must be unlocked; if so, custom recovery can be flashed. Of course that depends on the device, so what you wrote might be valid for the Note 2 (which I cannot tell as I don't have one to check – but obvioulsy OP flashed CWM before getting root to work ;)

Comment: Oops, accidentally wrote it lol. Factory ROMs are flashed and no root is needed. That was dumb of me, thanks for correction. And yes, recovery can be flashed without root. Thanks for correction once again :D

Comment: Actually I kinda wanted to say that since Sammy galaxy series bootloaders are already unlocked so we only need to install custom recovery and if that's installed.... It kinda came out wrong, thanks again for correction though